# Double pixel size of a window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gdi

Is there a way to double the pixel size of a window, and only that window, that draws to the screen using GDI?

Comment: What do you mean by "double pixel size"?  enlarge to 2x the size?

Comment: After extensive research, this can't be done.  You might want to try using a magnifier for a specific window, but apart from that...

Comment: @wizlog It can be done, it would just require me to get off of my lazy ass and code a DLL that hooks the drawing, window creation, and mouse position get functions and double everything.

Comment: If the software isn't readily available, you should of mentioned that, and offered more than a bounty of just 50 rep.

Comment: @wizlog I wasn't sure whether or not it was avaliable, and 50 was the max rep I put on a bounty.

Comment: I wasn't serious... Sorry.  If I knew how, I'd do it...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

- Change the DPI of the window? The answer is no.
- Change the dimensions of the window? The answer is yes via GetWindowPos/SetWindowPos.
- Zoom the window? Not unless you're using Direct2D/DirectX (in which case you can use a shader). You have to do this yourself.